# How to split nested string in Python?

Tags: python, string, parsing, split

I have dynamic string with some finite structure which is not possible to split as expected using basic .split() command. What are the ways to get desired result?

**Sample String:**

```
"array<struct<orderlineid:string,ordernumber:string,price:struct<currencycode:string,value:double>,quantity:int,serialnumbers:array<string>,sku:string>>"
```

**Split Goal:**

```
['orderlineid:string', 'ordernumber:string', 'price:struct<currencycode:string,value:double>','quantity:int','serialnumbers:array<string>', 'sku:string']
```

***Important Notice:** Someone advised to get rid of beginning and end of the string and use comma which is not working for this question because please see that nested struct also include comma inside which we do not want to split on.*

**Rules:**

First struct is always on which comes after "array" at the beginning. Second struct may be or may not be. If there is no second struct (which i called nested struct) solution is easy using split function on comma after getting rid of non-alphanumeric characters. But when i have nested struct there is also comma inside of that struct which i would like to take as whole without splitting.

Comment: Could you clarify what are the rules that you want to split the string on?

Comment: Why does the `price` struct remain intact? What is your *end* goal here? Is it simply to split the string how you've described, or is this part of a larger problem?

Comment: First struct is always on which comes after "array" at the beginning. Second struct may be or may not be. If there is no second struct (which i called nested struct) solution is easy using split function on comma after getting rid of non-alphanumeric characters. But when i have nested struct there is also comma inside of that struct which i would like to take as whole without splitting.

Comment: split isn't going to work very well with nested structures like this.  You need to parse this structure instead in order to deal with the array<struct parts and nested structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a nested structure encoding.  You seem to want the content of substructures at the second level of embedding.  So you can compute the nesting level of each character position, exclude levels 0 and 1 and split on the commas at level 2.  Since there are other commas, first replacing the splittable commas with another character would allow you to use a regular split for the extraction:

```
S = "array<struct<orderlineid:string,ordernumber:string,price:struct<currencycode:string,value:double>,quantity:int,serialnumbers:array<string>,sku:string>>"

from itertools import accumulate

levels = accumulate((c=="<")-(n==">") for c,n in zip(' '+S,S+' '))
delim  = "".join([c,"\n"][c=="," and lv==2] for c,lv in zip(S,levels) if lv>=2)
parts  = delim.split("\n")

print(parts)
['orderlineid:string', 'ordernumber:string', 
 'price:struct<currencycode:string,value:double>', 
 'quantity:int', 'serialnumbers:array<string>', 'sku:string']
```